# Create a PDF table

Tags: r

Is there a way to produce a PDF of a table from R in the same way you produce a plot (ie with pdf() or ggsave())? I realize there are ways with other programs (using sweave etc.), but I would like to produce it just from R.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes there is as you can place text into graphs and hence into pdf devices.

The nicest wrapper for this may be the `textplot()` function in Greg Warnes' trusted [gplots](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gplots) package. Below is the beginning of the examples section of its help page:

```
# show R version information
textplot(version)
# show the alphabet as a single string
textplot( paste(letters[1:26], collapse=" ") )

# show the alphabet as a matrix 
textplot( matrix(letters[1:26], ncol=2))

### Make a nice 4 way display with two plots and two text summaries 
data(iris)  
par(mfrow=c(2,2))   
plot( Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris, border="blue", col="cyan",   
      main="Boxplot of Sepal Length by Species" )    
plotmeans(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris, barwidth=2, connect=FALSE,
          main="Means and 95\% Confidence Intervals\nof Sepal Length by Species")

info <- sapply(split(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species),
               function(x) round(c(Mean=mean(x), SD=sd(x), N=gdata::nobs(x)),2))

textplot( info, valign="top"  )
title("Sepal Length by Species")

reg <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris )
textplot( capture.output(summary(reg)), valign="top")
title("Regression of Sepal Length by Species")

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 15):

see also `grid.table` in `gridExtra`, using grid graphics.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the addtable2plot function in the plotrix package.

Answer (score 4):

I recently wanted to do this but didn't like the output format of `grideExtra` or `textplot` so I wrote this function to do it in latex. It's a bit of a hack job and there are better ways with `sweave` or `knitr`, but you might find it useful to modify for your purposes:

```
createPDF <- function(xx, name=deparse(substitute(xx))){
  require(xtable)
  tt <- print(xtable(xx), type='latex')
  texfile <- paste0('./reports/', name, '.tex')
  cat(
    '\\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\\date{}
\\begin{document}', tt, '\\end{document}', sep='', 
    file=texfile
  )
  ## pdflatex from texlive package for linux converts .tex to .pdf
  system(paste0('pdflatex ', '-output-directory ./reports ', texfile))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using my library:

```
library(huxtable)
my_table <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl)
quick_pdf(my_table) # produces a PDF in the current directory
```