# How to create tables in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create and export a table for publication (picture attached).

I have created a table using the code below, but I could not export it as a table.

Can anyone help, please

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
data(gapminder)

median_gdp <- median(gapminder$gdpPercap)
gapminder %>%
select(-country) %>%
mutate(gdpPercap = ifelse(gdpPercap > median_gdp, "high", "low")) %>%
mutate(gdpPercap = factor(gdpPercap)) %>%
mutate(pop = pop / 1000000) -> gapminder

gapminder <- lapply(gapminder, function(x) x[sample(c(TRUE, NA),
                                                prob = c(0.9, 0.1),
                                                size = length(x),
                                                replace = TRUE
 )])

 library(arsenal)
 table_one <- tableby(continent ~ ., data = gapminder)
 summary(table_one, title = "Gapminder Data", text=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It might be easier to help if you could [edit] your question to include some more detail on what you mean by `export it as a table`. Are you needing a Word document with a table, LaTeX code for a table, etc.?

Comment: Why don't you export your data to csv (using `write.table`) and then format it on LibreOffice Calc or Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a table to Microsoft Word, you can use the following code from `arsenal` package.

```
write2word(table_one, "table.doc",
           keep.md = TRUE,
           quiet = TRUE,
           title = "Your title")
```

You can also write a table to pdf and HTML by using the `arsenal` package. For the details, see

```
?write2specific
```

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, there doesn't seem to be a general question on this topic, though see [Create a PDF table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881278/create-a-pdf-table) for PDFs.

Modern packages to print tables in output formats, including PDF, HTML and Word, include `gt`, `huxtable`, `flextable` and `kableExtra`.

Packages to create tables of summary statistics include `skimr`, `summarytools` and `qwraps2`. Some of these also have built-in output to different formats.

There are many other packages out there.