# Creating a table that it is publishable in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to create a table that looks publishable, but I have not been successful.

I have many tables that have very similar coding. The code looks like this...

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(totalM = length(wordsA),
            Ncue = length(unique(Cue)),
            overall = totalM/Ncue)
```

Then, when I export my results with rmarkdown I get in the pdf document something like this...

```
 category           totalM    Ncue      overall
  <chr>             <dbl>    <int>       <dbl>
1 Apositve           27.8      100       0.234
2 Anegative          14.5       40       0.236
3 Bpositive          26.2      100       0.223
4 Bnegative          12.2       50       0.246
5 Cpositive          28.7      100       0.248
6 Cnegative          11.6       50       0.223
7 Dpositive          29.3      100       0.231
8 Dnegative          14.1       50       0.230
```

So, it looks just like this. I want to add some code to make it look better.

I have been trying with some code that I saw on this platform, but I have not been successful with it.

I don't know if it can be done within R. If not I can always copy-paste it into a Word document and then edit it in Word

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: You could convert it to Latex format using e.g. the `texreg` or `xtable` packages. These packages can also convert to HTML.

Comment: You should take a look at the `pander` package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a PDF table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881278/create-a-pdf-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your data look better in Rmarkdown, check `kableExtra` package. Try this example:

```
library(kableExtra)
data <- data.frame(Letters=LETTERS[1:10],Numbers=1:10)
data %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_paper("hover", full_width = F)
```

Output:
[image]

There is others styles.